# How to get Location name from Hierarchical data in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Location` like this:

```
ID,   PID,   Location
1    NuLL    Country
2    1       City
3    2       County
4    3       District
5    4       Social
```

How can I make a view  in MySQL that returns this:

```
ID,   Location,   Full Location
1     Country     Country
2     City        City-Country
3     County      County-City-Country
4     District    District-County-City-Country
5     Social      Social-District-County-City-Country
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with joins or variables.  However, variables are not allowed in views.  So, something like this:

```
select concat_ws('-', l.location, l1.location, l2.location, l3.location, l4.location)
from location l left join
     location l1
     on l1.pid = l.id left join
     location l2
     on l2.pid = l1.id left join
     location l3
     on l3.pid = l2.id left join
     location l4
     on l4.pid = l3.id ;
```

Comment: It's was good to use when i know how many child level. But how can I do if I don't know how many child'll have?

Comment: @gianglaodai . . . MySQL has pitifully poor support for hierarchical queries.  You can generate a new table using a stored procedure (with a `while` loop).  But you cannot create a view for this type of query.

Comment: My level about database is terrible. Could you show me how to do it and how the database work?

Comment: @gianglaodai . . . It doesn't answer your question, because you cannot create a view that way.  You can add additional `join`s until you have reached a reasonable maximum.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I understand that MySQL can't create a view that way. I mean that can you show me the way you handle this problem with new table.

Comment: @gianglaodai . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  This one is specifically about views and what you are asking is much outside the scope of the question.